# Structure java classes (best practice)

Tags: java

I have written some Java classes to import the content of Excel file.

The content of the excel has mainly the following data types: static, dynamic and static dynamic together.

The question is what is the best structure to write the importer classes. I need methods to import dynamic, static and dynamic-static content

My idea is the following:

```
//Class to import dynamic content 
abstract class DynamicImporter{
void importDynamicExcel(){
}

//class to import static content
abstract class StaticImporter{
void importStaticExcel(){
}
```

Now the problem is that I have excel which have bouth dynamic and static content. It is not possible
to do something like this

```
abstract class DynamicStaticImporter extends StaticImporter, StaticImporter{

}
```

Any Idea what could be alternative to solve such kind of problems?

Comment: Inheritance in Java implies you can only extend *one* class at the time. You can, however, implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ExcelImporter` interface, an `AbstractExcelImporter` for shared code and the three implementations you need.

Comment: mybe more details? for what do I need the interface?

Comment: This way you can loop over your ExcelImporters until one of them successfully parses your document. Gives you good encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need one abstract class with shared implementation. There is no need for 3 abstract classes. Alternatively you can use builder pattern for composition

```
abstract class AbstractExcelImporter{
  void importExcel(){
    //implementation 
 }
}

//Class to import dynamic content 
class DynamicImporter extends AbstractExcelImporter{
   void importDynamicExcel(){
      importExcel();
      //type spesific implementation or overridde importExcel method 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to implementing dispatch on multiple inheritance is to flatten the hierarchy into a single class, and give it a single method that takes a descriptor of what kind of import to do (static, dynamic, etc.) as its parameter:

```
enum ImportType {
    STATIC
,   DYNAMIC
,   STATIC_DYNAMIC
}

class Importer {
    void importExcel(ImportType impType) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In turn `ImportType` enumeration could be enhanced with properties and methods directing the process of importing Excel data into your application.

Comment: Then you end up with a switch-statement or something like that to handle each case. Using polymorphism for this gives you the more flexible solution.

Comment: @leftbit You seem to have missed the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: No, didn't miss it. Doing it your way Importer would (worst case) contain several branches depending on ImportType and associated properties. ImportType really can't contain any useful methods if you keep the public interface of the Importer lean and concise. Of course, your alternative would work, but it violates the "separation of concerns" design principle.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit of two disctinct classes but you can implements as many interface as you want. You can do something like that :

```
interface DynamicImporter{
  void importDynamicExcel(){
  }
}

interface StaticImporter{
  void importStaticExcel(){
  }
}
```

And then, your class becomes :

```
abstract class DynamicStaticImporter implements StaticImporter, StaticImporter{

}
```

If you need some common code, you can also have

```
abstract class AbstractImporter {
   someMethod() {
   }
}
```

In that case, your class will become :

```
abstract class DynamicStaticImporter extends AbstractImporter implements StaticImporter, StaticImporter{

}
```

Comment: How to import/use StaticImporter.importStaticExcel() and DynamicImporter.importDynamicExcel() from DynamicStaticImporter?

Comment: You don't have the code in StaticImporter and DynamicImporter because they're interface. You will only use DynamicStaticImporter methods